# What determines the color of contextual action bar title and divider

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I'm asking this because, my cab's title and color were white and all of the sudden when I am almost at the end of my project they are black. And I didn't mess with cab since I've set it.

Comment: Did you change the base theme?

Comment: Nope it has been Theme.Holo.Light from the start